# My table cells don't highlight immediately when touched

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In my app, I have a table view that has about eight cells. There is a navigation bar at the top. When a user touches a cell, nothing happens for about 1/2 second. Then the touched cell highlights blue and immediately the new view slides into position.

The problem is that there is no feedback to the user about which cell he touched until **just** before the new view slides into position.

For example, when I explore the tables in the iPhone's Settings application, when you touch a cell, the cell *immediately* turns blue, and then there is a 1/2 second delay, and then you see the new view.

How do I get my table's feedback of highlighting the cells to happen immediately? I am using tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, and each cell has an accessory button.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

are you using a custom-drawn cell (with a drawRect override) or something like that?

if you have a custom drawRect method, you'll need to do something like this (based off the code for tweetie, found [here](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/)):

```
//default colors for cell
UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIColor *textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

//on highlight, swap colors
if(self.highlighted){
    backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

that should give you the default behavior.

Comment: Hi, kolywater,
I'm not using a custom-drawn cell at all.  I just assign the text to the cell.  I really don't want to be responsible for drawing the entire cell, and I'm looking for a reason the cell delays so much in highlighting after it's touched.  Seems the OS should be taking care of that!
/Steve

Comment: if you remove everything from your didSelectRowAtIndex method, does the highlighting work?

can you also post your didSelectRowAtIndex code?

Comment: Hi, kolywater, I'm answering this in the post below, because quick comment will only allow me 600 characters.

Comment: Had the same issue and I am using ABTableViewCells. In the example, it was if(self.selected). Had to replace it with if(self.selected || self.highlighted). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the screen is refreshing after the new slide has been processed.  You need to refresh the screen before rendering the new slide view.

Comment: Hi, Robert,
Thanks for responding.  I'm kind of a newbie.  How do I "refresh" the screen?
/SD

Comment: Apparently it's not as easy as I thought: http://www.thebitsource.com/2009/04/12/a-web-developer-perspective-on-iphone-software-development/  However, it can be done, see this page for some examples:  http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=1793

Comment: Hi, Robert,

I'm a little stuck.  Seems to me that what I'm seeking should be the default operation of the cells.  I shouldn't have to write code to highlight the cell when it's selected, should I?  I'm wondering what could be causing such a delay.
/Steve

Comment: Steve, these guys seem to know what they're doing: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11422-how-refresh-one-region-screen.html.  My relevant experience has more to do with general UI and less to do with the IPhone proper.

Answer (score 0):

a few things:

it's probably best to have a property in beforeViewController so it can set its own title on load (instead of setting it from the parent class).

second, why are you setting the back button for the current class? youre also leaking that (you alloc the UIBarButtonItem but dont release it).

```
NewViewController *newViewController = [[[NewViewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"New" bundle:nil] autorelease];
newViewController.name = [self.listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:beforeAfterViewController animated:YES];
```

then in NewViewController, you have

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    self.title = self.name;
}
```

re: your secondary question: if you pop the child controller using [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES], the parent view should auto-deselect the row that was previously selected. it shoulnt stay selected unless you are forcing it to stay that way.

you don't need to do anything like [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:] unless you are not pushing child views (and doing something like checkmarking a cell that the user tapped).

Answer (score 0):

You may put these 2 lines of code at the beginning of the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
```

it should first highlight the cell before processing other program logic.